# bash: clean and merge data

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, data-science

I have three csv files containing different data for a common object. These represent data about distinct collections of items at work. These objects have unique codes. The number of files is not important so I will set this problem up with two. I have a handy recipe for joining these files using `join` -- but the cleaning part is killing me.

File A snippet - contains unique data. Also the cataloging error `E B`.

```
B    547
J    65
EB   289
E B  1
CO   8900
ZX   7
```

File B snippet - unique data about a different dimension of the objects.

```
B    5
ZX   67
SD   4
CO   76
J    54
EB   10
```

Note that file B contains a code not in common with file A.

Now I submit to you the "official" canon of codes designated for this set of objects:

```
B
CO
ZX
J
EB
```

Note that File B contains a non-canonical code with data. It needs to be captured and documented. Same with bad code in file A.

End goal: run trend and stats on the collections using the various fields from the multiple reports. They mostly match the canon but there are oddballs due to cataloging errors and codes that are no longer in use.

End goal result after merge/join:

```
B    547    5
J    65     54
EB   289    10
CO   8900   76
ZX   7      67
```

So my first idea was to use `grep -F -f` for this, using the canonical codes as a search list then merge with `join`. Problem is, with one letter codes it's too inclusive. It would seem like a job for `awk` where it can work with `tab` delimiters and `REGEX` the oddball codes. I'm not sure though, how to get `awk` to use a list to sift other files. Will `join` alone handle all this? Maybe I merge with `join` or `paste`, then sift out the weirdos? Which method is the least brittle and more likely to handle edge cases like the drunk cataloger?

If you're thinking, "Dude, this is better done with Perl or Python ...etc.". I'm all ears. No rules, I just need to deliver!

Comment: So why is the `SD` entry in the desired output as an oddball, while the `E B` entry is not?

Comment: @cody I'm debating as to how to present the data. I think I should pull them out and present them separately as my math routines aren't going to produce anything of value, given that they will be missing crucial fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question says the data is csv, but based on your samples I'm assuming it's tsv. I'm also assuming `E B` should end up in the outlier output and that NA values should be filled with `0`.

Given those assumptions, the following may be sufficient:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 1b,1 fileA > fileA.sorted && sort -t $'\t' -k 1b,1 fileB > fileB.sorted
join -t $'\t' -a1 -a2 -e0 -o auto fileA.sorted fileB.sorted > out
grep -f codes out > out-canon
grep -vf codes out > out-oddball
```

The content of file `codes`:

```
^B\s
^CO\s
^ZX\s
^J\s
^EB\s
```

Result:

```
$ cat out-canon
B       547     5
CO      8900    76
EB      289     10
J       65      54
ZX      7       67

$ cat out-oddball
E B     1       0
SD      0       4
```

Comment: It's tab delimited.

Comment: I'm not sure your `grep -f` would work in the case where `E` is canonical and `E B` is a cataloger mistake in the file. This is what I keep running into.

Comment: Ah -- I get it. You added the REGEX in the codes file. Smart! OK.

Comment: I will test soon and hit the checkmark upon success. Pretty sure this will work. The REGEX in the codes file pretty much slam dunks this and massively reduces fragility. In the meantime ...upvoted! Thanks!

Comment: Breaks on `E B` but I swapped out `\s` with `\t` and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this(GNU awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t";}ARGIND==1{c[$1]++;}ARGIND==2{b[$1]=$2}ARGIND==3{if (c[$1]) {print $1,$2,b[$1]+0; delete b[$1];} else {if(tolower($1)~"[a-z]+ +[a-z]+")print>"error.fileA"; else print>"oddball.fileA";}}END{for (i in b) {print i,0,b[i] " (? maybe?)";print i,b[i] > "oddball.fileB";}}' codes fileB fileA
```

It will create `error.fileA`, `oddball.fileA` if such lines exists, `oddball.fileB`.
Normal output didn't write to file, you can write with `>` yourself when results are ok:

```
B   547 5
J   65  54
EB  289 10
CO  8900    76
ZX  7   67
SD  0   4 (? maybe?)
```

Had a hard time reading your description, not sure if this is what you want.
Anyway it's easy to improve this awk code.

You can change to `FILENAME=="file1"`, or `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` if `ARGIND` is not working.